# get sum from list of objects in linq C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have list of objects as described below:

```
List<Maths> mObjs = new List<Maths>();
mObjs.Add(new Maths{ Name = "Jack", M1 = 10, M2 = 5, M3 = 0, M4 = 2, M5 =1 });
mObjs.Add(new Maths { Name = "Jill", M1 = 2, M2 = 3, M3 = 4, M4 = 1, M5 = 0 });
mObjs.Add(new Maths { Name = "Michel", M1 = 12, M2 = 15, M3 = 10, M4 = 12, M5 = 11 });
```

Now I need to calculated the total aggregated value for all three people.
I need to get the below results, probably a new other class

```
List<Results> mRes = new List<Results>();

public class Results{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TotalValue { get; set; }

}

mRes.Name = "M1"
mRes.TotalValue  = 24;

mRes.Name = "M2"
mRes.TotalValue  = 23;

mRes.Name = "M3"
mRes.TotalValue  = 14;

mRes.Name = "M4"
mRes.TotalValue  = 15;


mRes.Name = "M5"
mRes.TotalValue  = 12;
```

How can I get this data from mObjs using linq query? I know we can do it using for, but want to know if there are any better ways to get this using linq query because that reduces lines of code and I have similar requirements in many other places and dont want to write number of foreach or fors every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pre selection list to list both the name and the field to select

```
var lookups = new Dictionary<string,Func<Maths,int>> {
    {"M1", x => x.M1 },
    {"M2", x => x.M2 },
    {"M3", x => x.M3 },
    {"M4", x => x.M4 },
    {"M5", x => x.M5 },
};
```

Then you can simply do

```
var mRes = dlookups.Select(x => new Results { 
                                              Name= x.Key,
                                              TotalValue = mObjs.Sum(x.Value)
                           }).ToList();
```

**BEGIN UPDATED***

In response to comments

The lambda expression is just a function from your source class to an int.

For example

```
class Sub1 {
  string M3 {get;set;}
  int M4 {get;set;}
}

class Math2 {
  string Name {get;set;}
  string M1 {get;set;}
  string M2 {get;set;}
  Sub1 Sub {get;set;}
}

var lookups = new Dictionary<string,Func<Math2,int>> {
   { "M1", x => int.Parse(x.M1) },
   { "M2", x => int.Parse(x.M2) },
   { "M3", x => int.Parse(x.Sub.M3) },
   { "M4", x => int.Parse(x.Sub.M4} }
};
```

Or if you want to put a little error checking in, you can either use functions or embed the code.

```
int GetInt(string source) {
  if (source == null) return 0;
  int result;
  return int.TryParse(source, out result) ? result : 0;
}

var lookups = new Dictionary<string,Func<Math2,int>> {
   { "M1", x => {
                  int result;
                  return x == null ? 0 : (int.TryParse(x,out result) ? result : 0);
                },
   { "M2", x => GetInt(x) },
   { "M3", x => x.Sub == null ? 0 : GetInt(x.Sub.M3) },
   { "M4", x => x.Sub == null ? 0 : x.Sub.M4}
};
```

**END UPDATED**

If you want to go further you could use reflection to build the lookups dictionary.

Here is a helper function that will generate the lookups for all Integer properties of a class.

```
public Dictionary<string,Func<T,int>> GenerateLookups<T>() where T: class {
    // This just looks for int properties, you could add your own filter
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(int));

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

  return properties.Select(x => new { 
     Key = x.Name, 
     Value = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,int>>(Expression.Property(parameter,x),parameter).Compile()
  }).ToDictionary (x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

}
```

Now you can just do:

```
 var mRes=GenerateLookups<Maths>().Select( x => new Results
   {
     Name = x.Key,
     TotalValue = mObjs.Sum(x.Value)
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: facing little problem here. In other class points are stored in string variable. how can I convert that string property to int?

Comment: @mmssaann Are you using the full reflection version or just the lookups?

Comment: i just need the looks, unfortunately they are stored in different types in different classes though the value in it is int.

Answer (score 1):

Not very smart but efficient and readable:

```
int m1Total= 0;
int m2Total= 0;
int m3Total= 0;
int m4Total= 0;
int m5Total= 0;
foreach(Maths m in mObjs)
{
    m1Total += m.M1;
    m2Total += m.M2;
    m3Total += m.M3;
    m4Total += m.M4;
    m5Total += m.M5;
}
List<Results> mRes = new List<Results>
{
    new Results{ Name = "M1", TotalValue = m1Total },
    new Results{ Name = "M2", TotalValue = m2Total },
    new Results{ Name = "M3", TotalValue = m3Total },
    new Results{ Name = "M4", TotalValue = m4Total },
    new Results{ Name = "M5", TotalValue = m5Total },
};
```

Result:

```
Name: "M1"  TotalValue: 24  
Name: "M2"  TotalValue: 23  
Name: "M3"  TotalValue: 14  
Name: "M4"  TotalValue: 15  
Name: "M5"  TotalValue: 12
```

**Edit**: since you've explicitly asked for LINQ, if the properties are always these five i don't see why you need to use LINQ at all. If the number can change i would use a different structure.

You could for example use

- a single `List<Measurement>` instead of multiple properties where `Measurement` is another class that stores the name and the value or you could use
- a `Dictionary<string, int>` for efficient lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out some thing like this :

```
mRes.Add(new Results() { Name = "M1", TotalValue = mObjs.Sum(x => x.M1) });
```

To programmatically iterate through all the class properties, you might need to employ reflection.